# Why won't these buttons float left or display inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple piece of code that makes some links sit in the top right corner of the page, but they won't line up nicely. They keep lining up vertically, and I want them horizontal. I'm sure it's probably something obvious I'm missing, but I'm not sure what. I also tried using float left but it didn't change anything.

**CSS & HTML**

```css
.social {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  /*   display:inline-block; */
  /*   float:left; */
}
.social-buttons-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*   display: inline-block; */
  /*   float:right; */
}
.social-button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*   float:right; */
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="social-buttons-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Twitter.png" alt="" class="social-button">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Facebook.png" alt="" class="social-button">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Snapchat.png" alt="" class="social-button">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You're forgetting that the `<li>` of your list has a default `display:block`.  By addressing that and adding `text-align: right` to your list you'll achieve a horizontal, right-aligned list.

```css
.social {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  /*   display:inline-block; */
  /*   float:left; */
}
.social-buttons-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*   display: inline-block; */
  /*   float:right; */
  text-align: right;
}
.social-buttons-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.social-button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*   float:right; */
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <ul class="social-buttons-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Twitter.png" alt="" class="social-button">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Facebook.png" alt="" class="social-button">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Snapchat.png" alt="" class="social-button">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are aligning because you have the buttons in "un-ordered list" , they are used to display list. Just remove them

```css
.social {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  /*   display:inline-block; */
  /*   float:left; */
}
.social-buttons-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*   display: inline-block; */
  /*   float:right; */
}
.social-button {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*   float:right; */
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Twitter.png" a class="social-button">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Facebook.png"  class="social-button">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="img/Snapchat.png"  class="social-button">
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Although the ideal answer would fix the problem without altering the structure, this answer does work and is more simple than the "ideal answer". Thanks for the response.

Comment: there are different ways, depends on what you need !! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLBBWG

Here is your solution

Comment: You may have technically solved the exact scope of my problem, using generic tags instead of the classes I outlined makes it so I can't put this in my code because it could break other things. Also you didn't offer an explanation which would have been more useful. Thanks anyways.